# Xamarin.Forms Android APK behaves with complications after shrinking it

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, mono

Initially, my APK was **40mb** and it was working very well but I wanted to shrink it, then after shrinking it with **Link all assemblies** the apk size is **13mb** but the application Network is not to work any more, the application doesn't log in.

What causes all these complications, I tried to a lot of research on this but I couldn't get a clear answer.

**Below is my configuration:**

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your linker is cleaning up your code, you can check my blog here https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/reducing-the-app-size-in-xamarin-deep-dive-7ddc9cb12688

Comment: @G.hakim, I sent you a requst on linkedIn, kindly needed further exp;lanation on your blog post. Thanks

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris Have you soled this problem?

Comment: No @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris You can have a try with this:`[Android.Runtime.Preserve (AllMembers = true)]`.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker#preserving-code